# html <select> jquery mix it up not working ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

Hello I'm using jquery mix it up plugin for a portfolio section of a web. Everything is ok. But I builded a select option menu for mobile devices only (using bootstrap classes hidden-xs and visible-xs). In normal browser works ok, but in iphone not working. I can select option but nothing happen. Mix it up effect not appear like the rest of browsers.

This is my html

```
<select class="visible-xs form-control " id="filters">
<option class="filter active"  data-filter="cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5"><span >All</span></option>
<option class="filter" data-filter="cat1"><span >Cat1</span></option>
<option class="filter" data-filter="cat2"><span>Cat2</span></option>
<option class="filter" data-filter="cat3"><span >Cat3</span></option>
<option class="filter" data-filter="cat4"><span>Cat4</span></option>
<option class="filter" data-filter="cat5"><span>Cat5</span></option>
</select>
<ul id="filters" class="hidden-xs clearfix">
<li><span class="filter active" data-filter="cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5">All</span></li>
<li><span class="filter" data-filter="cat1">Innovación</span></li>
<li><span class="filter" data-filter="cat2">Investigación</span></li>
<li><span class="filter" data-filter="cat3">Artículos</span></li>
<li><span class="filter" data-filter="cat4">Libros</span></li>
<li><span class="filter" data-filter="cat5">Web</span></li>
</ul>

<div id="portfoliolist">
....the code of each item....
```

and this is my Java code:

```
$(function () {

        var filterList = {

            init: function () {

                // MixItUp plugin
                // http://mixitup.io
                $('#portfoliolist').mixitup({
                    targetSelector: '.portfolio',
                    filterSelector: '.filter',
                    effects: ['fade'],
                    easing: 'smooth',
                    // call the hover effect
                    onMixEnd: filterList.hoverEffect()
                });             

            },

            hoverEffect: function () {

                // Simple parallax effect
                $('#portfoliolist .portfolio').hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).find('.label-content').stop().animate({bottom: 0}, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
                        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({top: -100}, 500, 'easeOutQuad');                
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).find('.label-content').stop().animate({bottom: -100}, 200, 'easeInQuad');
                        $(this).find('img').stop().animate({top: 0}, 300, 'easeOutQuad');                               
                    }       
                );              

            }

        };

        // Run the show!
        filterList.init();


    });
```

Anybody knows what could be wrong??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MixItUp, but after looking at the documentation for a minute, they explain how the filter works here: 
http://mixitup.io/#FilterSelector

It looks like its adding a click event, and since you are using a select field, its not firing a click event.  You can manually call the filter options though, based on the value change of the select box.

Make your select something like this:

```
<select class="visible-xs form-control " id="filters">
    <option value="cat1 cat2 cat3 cat4 cat5">All</option>
    <option value="cat1">Cat1</option>
    <option value="cat2">Cat2</option>
    <option value="cat3">Cat3</option>
    <option value="cat4">Cat4</option>
    <option value="cat5">Cat5</option>
</select>
```

And call the filter method when the value changes:

```
$('#filters').on('change', function() { 
   $('#portfoliolist').mixitup('filter',this.value);
});
```

Here's a JS fiddle of this, its alerting the selection, the filter code is commented out. http://jsfiddle.net/Xk7Bp/

UPDATE: Also, you have multiple items with the same `id="filters"` which is invalid and may lead to issues.

Comment: Works like a charm! I thought I had to filter with data-filter, not with value option :( Thanks so much!

Comment: data-* is used in javascript to store arbitrary data, its the value of it that you needed to pass.  Options have a built in value attribute, so it makes more sense to use that.